# KDC has no support for encryption type while authentication to OpenLDAP

Tags: openldap, kerberos

I'm running a Kerberos / LDAP authentication server for many years. Kerberos data is stored inside LDAP. Now, I have a second site and want to mirror the server to the new site. This basically works, but there is a strange side effect. Each server has a KDC and a LDAP running. KDC talks to LDAP using local ldapi:///.

If I use the original KDC `krb1.example.com` I can authenticate to the master LDAP and the replica. If I use the replicated KDC `krb2.example.com`, I can still authenticate to the master LDAP, but trying the replica I get

```
SASL/GSSAPI authentication started
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Local error (-2)
        additional info: SASL(-1): generic failure: GSSAPI Error: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information (KDC has no support for encryption type)
```

Which is strange, since `krb2` is literally a clone on the LXC container `krb1` i.e. the configurations are identical safe for the changes required for replication. But still more puzzeling is a look into the ticket caches after trying to query either LDAP server. With a TGT from `krb1`

```
root@krb2:/# klist -e
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5_cc_0.tkt
Default principal: user@EXAMPLE.COM

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
04.02.2022 01:05:29  04.02.2022 11:05:29  krbtgt/EXAMPLE.COM@EXAMPLE.COM
        renew until 05.02.2022 01:05:26, Etype (skey, tkt): aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96, aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 
04.02.2022 01:05:42  04.02.2022 11:05:29  ldap/krb1.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
        renew until 05.02.2022 01:05:26, Etype (skey, tkt): aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96, aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 
04.02.2022 01:05:53  04.02.2022 11:05:29  ldap/krb2.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
        renew until 05.02.2022 01:05:26, Etype (skey, tkt): aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96, aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96
```

and from `krb2`:

```
root@krb2:/# klist -e
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5_cc_0.tkt
Default principal: user@EXAMPLE.COM

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
04.02.2022 00:53:45  04.02.2022 10:53:45  krbtgt/EXAMPLE.COM@EXAMPLE.COM
        renew until 05.02.2022 00:53:41, Etype (skey, tkt): aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96, aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 
04.02.2022 00:53:47  04.02.2022 10:53:45  ldap/krb1.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
        renew until 05.02.2022 00:53:41, Etype (skey, tkt): aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96, aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96
```

which has no entry for `ldap/krb2.example.com` due to the error. But apparently there is no difference in the encryption types required. So, why does it complain?

Currently both LDAP servers refer to `krb1`. But due to the LDAP replication all keys should be identical i.e. a key from `krb1` should be the same as from `krb2`, shouldn't it? And if keys from `krb1` work for both LDAP servers, why does the key from the replica server only work for the master LDAP?

`supported_enctypes` for the realm in both `/etc/krb5kdc/kdc.conf` are `supported_enctypes = aes256-cts:normal arcfour-hmac:normal des3-hmac-sha1:normal des-cbc-crc:normal des:normal des:v4 des:norealm des:onlyrealm des:afs3`. There are no enctype directives in either `/etc/krb5.conf`. There are no `ssf` configuration used in either LDAP. The `krbPrincipalName` entries for `krb2` exist in both LDAP.

Even if I obtain the TGT from `krb2` and then switch the `krb5.conf` to `krb1` for the service ticket, I can authenticate to LDAP on `krb2`.

OpenLDAP is in version 2.4.47, Kerberos 1.17 on both machines (current Debian stable).

**Update:** It turned out that replication is incomplete i.e., `krbPrincipalKey` is not (reliably) replicated. I checked the `slapd` debugging output:

```
Feb  9 19:14:52 krb1 slapd[19560]: conn=1300 op=3 BIND authcid="sync/krb2.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM" authzid="dn:uid=sync/krb2.example.com,cn=example.com,cn=gssapi,cn=auth@EXAMPLE.COM"
Feb  9 19:14:52 krb1 slapd[19560]: conn=1300 op=3 BIND dn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" mech=GSSAPI sasl_ssf=256 ssf=256
```

So, `synprov` apparently binds as `cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com`, which is intended.However, if I do

```
root@krb1:~# ldapsearch -b 'cn=KERBEROS,dc=example,dc=com' -D 'cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com' -Wx 'krbPrincipalName=ldap/krb2.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM'
```

then I see `krbPrincipalKey`. So why doesn't it get replicated?

I restart `slapd` on `krb2` with options `-c rid=1,csn=0`, which I understood should sync the entire database. But since some entries have a key and some don't, I do not trust that this is true.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Currently both LDAP servers refer to krb1"? Are you talking about KDCs in krb5.conf, or about keytabs, or something else?

Comment: Can you show the actual authentication process that is failing? If the containers are exact clones, does the LDAP service on kdc2 _know_ that it's now called `ldap/kdc2` rather than `ldap/kdc1`, i.e. does it at least have a new keytab for its new name, or is it still using the original keytab?

Comment: Yes, hostname, IP address, DNS entry, keytab, TLS certificates have been adapted to match the new instance.

Comment: So what I did is: ldapsearch -b "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" -H ldap://kdc?.uac.microsult.de. Setting /etc/krb5.conf to kdc2, I can do kinit, I can query kdc1, but kdc2 fails. If I then change kdc to krb1 in /etc/krb5.conf, the query to kdc2 succeeds as well using the very same ticket.

Comment: Can you manually request a ticket from the 'kdc2' KDC using `KRB5_TRACE=/dev/stderr kvno ldap/kdc2.uac.microsult.de`, and if that fails, what does krb5kdc report to its log file? Can you verify that both KDCs have the same information in their LDAP replicas (e.g. by dumping them both via slapcat, or via ldapsearch with rootdn/rootpw authentication)? Can you run `kadmin.local` in both KDCs to check what they know about the ldap/kdc2 principal?

Comment: Ah, and you really shouldn't have that "supported_enctypes" setting... it probably doesn't _hurt_ (yet), but the list is already quite stale, and having it explicitly configured doesn't serve any good purpose.

Comment: The ```kadmin.local``` hint showed that the replica server actually has no keys for some principals. I didn't see this since my admin principal for LDAP neither sees keys due to ACL i.e., the entries looked the same on both servers. However, the replication principal should see keys. So it seems I have to troubleshoot the ```slapd``` ACL and Authzid. I did not yet find any suitable debug value to see, which users use which authzid to which DN. But this at least is a pure LDAP configuration issue.

Comment: `stats` log level would be a good start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by `slapcat` the master database and `slapadd` from scratch on the consumer.

Thanks to user1686 for pointing to the things to check to make me break circular thoughts.

The cause of the issue was that some Kerberos principals in the LDAP had no `krbPrincipalKey` attribute. `ldap/krb2.example.com` being one of those. This became obvious using `get_principal` in `kadmin.local` on each server. The confusion arose due to using inappropriate bind DN and the ACL associated with those. Furthermore, I trusted that I used options for `slapd` to re-fetch the entire database on start-up, which did not happen.

Some pitfalls that kept me trapped: Since with TLS enabled `-Y EXTERNAL` does not work, I use special Kerberos principals for database maintenance. My principal for `cn=config` has no access to credentials stored in the main database, which I was not aware of anymore. So comparing entries of the two LDAP yielded identical results. While the actual replication principal has access to credentials, I probably used the other bind DN initially i.e., before I had Kerberos set up for replication. Therefore, the entries created during this time period were replicated without credentials, and `syncprov` does not fix this later.